# Maven java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver proyect not using my dependency

Tags: java, mysql, maven, glassfish

I'm trying to test the connection of my web app and i keep getting the same error (I'm using Apache Netbeans and glassfish server)
[image]

Here's my pom.xml

[image]

and this is my servlet that test the connection
[image]

Don't know if it helps but here is the glassfish log:
[image]

Comment: Get rid of the `Class.forName().`. It names the wrong class, and it hasn't been needed at all since 2007. And don't post pictures of text here. Post the text.

Answer (score 0):

Application Server needs a database driver-jar in its library folder to load the driver class to create connect pools. Try placing the mysql.jar into the sever library folder at glassfish\lib.

Further, you are trying to manually load the database driver class in your servlet using Class.forname. This is not a best practice when you are using the application server. It would be better if you configure your data source in the application server and use JNDI lookup to get the database connection. You can also configure connection pools for better performance.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, i place the connector jar in the glassfish lib and restarted, I'm getting this error now

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:C:\Users\Sarl\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
¿any idea of what this is?

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?